# Minecraft Entity Registry failed on Server load

Tags: java, crash, minecraft, minecraft-forge

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this code works fine in the client based launcher, but as soon as you try to register the entities, the server cracked's the shits.

Here is the code, I'm just lost now, I've also tried the other way of registering, but that did nothing as well.

```
    package com.muddykat.grimoire.entity;

import com.muddykat.grimoire.entity.mob.EntityImp;
import com.muddykat.grimoire.entity.mob.EntityProwler;
import com.muddykat.grimoire.lib.GrimoireLib;

import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityEntry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityEntryBuilder;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;

@Mod.EventBusSubscriber
public class EntityReg {
    private EntityReg() {
    }

    public static void preInit() {
        //registerEntity(EntityImp.class, "demon_imp", 0x660000, 0xB8AB8D);
        //registerEntity(EntityProwler.class, "demon_prowler", 0x660000, 0xB8AB8D);
    }

    private static int id = 0;


    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerEntities(RegistryEvent.Register<EntityEntry> event) {
        EntityEntry imp = EntityEntryBuilder.create()
                .entity(EntityImp.class)
                .id(new ResourceLocation(GrimoireLib.MODID + ":demon_imp"), id++)
                .name("grimoire.demon_imp")
                .egg(0x660000, 0xB8AB8D)
                .tracker(64, 3, true)
                .build();
            event.getRegistry().register(imp);

        EntityEntry prowler = EntityEntryBuilder.create()
                .entity(EntityProwler.class)
                .id(new ResourceLocation(GrimoireLib.MODID + ":demon_prowler"), id++)
                .name("grimoire.demon_prowler")
                .egg(0x660000, 0xB8AB8D)
                .tracker(64, 3, true)
                .build();
            event.getRegistry().register(prowler);
    }
}
```

here is the crash log

```
    ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// This doesn't make any sense!

Time: 12/17/18 6:49 PM
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/client/multiplayer/WorldClient
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ReflectionHelper.findConstructor(ReflectionHelper.java:255)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityEntryBuilder$ConstructorFactory.<init>(EntityEntryBuilder.java:298)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityEntryBuilder$1.<init>(EntityEntryBuilder.java:266)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityEntryBuilder.build(EntityEntryBuilder.java:266)
    at com.muddykat.grimoire.entity.EntityReg.registerEntities(EntityReg.java:37)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler_5_EntityReg_registerEntities_Register.invoke(.dynamic)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:90)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus$1.invoke(EventBus.java:144)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:182)
    at net.minecraftforge.registries.GameData.fireRegistryEvents(GameData.java:789)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:628)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.server.FMLServerHandler.beginServerLoading(FMLServerHandler.java:99)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler.onServerStart(FMLCommonHandler.java:333)
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:128)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:552)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: net.minecraftforge.fml.common.asm.ASMTransformerWrapper$TransformerException: Exception in class transformer net.minecraftforge.fml.common.asm.transformers.SideTransformer@14f3c6fc from coremod FMLCorePlugin
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.asm.ASMTransformerWrapper$TransformerWrapper.transform(ASMTransformerWrapper.java:260)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.runTransformers(LaunchClassLoader.java:279)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:176)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to load class net/minecraft/client/multiplayer/WorldClient for invalid side SERVER
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.asm.transformers.SideTransformer.transform(SideTransformer.java:62)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.asm.ASMTransformerWrapper$TransformerWrapper.transform(ASMTransformerWrapper.java:256)
    ... 24 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_181, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 879695752 bytes (838 MB) / 1038876672 bytes (990 MB) up to 1038876672 bytes (990 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2768 6 mods loaded, 6 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

    | State | ID        | Version      | Source                           | Signature |
    |:----- |:--------- |:------------ |:-------------------------------- |:--------- |
    | UCH   | minecraft | 1.12.2       | minecraft.jar                    | None      |
    | UCH   | mcp       | 9.42         | minecraft.jar                    | None      |
    | UCH   | FML       | 8.0.99.99    | forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768.jar | None      |
    | UCH   | forge     | 14.23.5.2768 | forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768.jar | None      |
    | UCH   | grimoire  | 1.0          | bin                              | None      |
    | UCH   | jei       | 4.13.1.225   | jei_1.12.2-4.13.1.225.jar        | None      |

    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Is Modded: Definitely; Server brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Dedicated Server (map_server.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Because the server doesn't know what renderers (and some other stuff) are

There are certain classes that only appear on the client side of things (the dedicated server jar is *not* the same as the client jar) because the server does not render anything, doesn't know what a keyboard is, and does not play audio.

Lets look at the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/client/multiplayer/WorldClient
     at com.muddykat.grimoire.entity.EntityReg.registerEntities(EntityReg.java:37)
```

The class that can't be found is in `net.minecraft.client` (that's the client-only stuff!) and is called `WorldClient`, which is used by the client to store the world data locally (changes made to it are largely ignored and get overwritten when the server sends an update). The error stack trace had a lot of stuff in it, but it does contain from a call within your code in your entities registration. Its a few lines down, but that doesn't mean you're not at fault (you are).

I can't tell which line is line 37, but one of your two entity classes likely contains a reference to `WorldClient` and when you pass that class off to the EntityBuilder, the JVM looks at the class and asks, "Can I find all of the references this class makes?" Finds one for `WorldClient` and goes, "Nope! I've got no idea what that one is" and crashes....Even if that reverence will never get called (the JVM has no way of knowing this).

Further diagnosis will require seeing the code for your entities.